# RuntimeError: Calling `rasa.core.run` directly is no longer supported. Please use `rasa shell` instead

Tags: python-2.7, docker, rasa-nlu, rasa-core

When i try to run rasa-nlu using docker, i got the following issue:

```
Attaching to chatbotstack_rasa_nlu_1
rasa_nlu_1         | Traceback (most recent call last):
rasa_nlu_1         |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
rasa_nlu_1         |     "__main__", mod_spec)
rasa_nlu_1         |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
rasa_nlu_1         |     exec(code, run_globals)
rasa_nlu_1         |   File "/app/rasa/core/run.py", line 204, in <module>
rasa_nlu_1         |     "Calling `rasa.core.run` directly is "
rasa_nlu_1         | RuntimeError: Calling `rasa.core.run` directly is no longer supported. Please use `rasa shell` instead.
```

I have specified versions below:

```
rasa                    0.14.0a9 /app    
rasa-addons             0.5.9    
rasa-core               0.13.7   
rasa-core-sdk           0.12.2   
rasa-nlu                0.14.6
```

Answer (score 0):

Rasa `0.14.0a9` is currently an alpha version and the new docs are not yet released. Either uninstall the `rasa` package and use the stable releases `rasa_core==0.13.7` and `rasa_nlu==0.14.6` or use the new cli `rasa shell`.